# Cannot figure out how to revert back to backed up profile file

Tags: shell, ubuntu, tty

Basically, I made a backup copy of my `/etc/profile` (or `~/.profile` I can't remember exactly) file that executes as soon as you login to a TTY, and then I changed the one that was there, and now it automatically logs you out as soon as you login.

I just need to view the current file and make a modification to the script, but I can't figure out a way to get to it.

I've tried a Ubuntu live CD but I can't figure out how to get permission after I mount the drive locally.

I have Grub installed but I removed all of the options except the default from the menu.

Edit: also if it's relevant, I the disk is a `.vhd` that I am trying to access via virtualbox.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use a different shell

You could try running a different shell like this:

```
$ ssh -t remoteserver '/bin/csh'
```

Once in you can move the files that you need to, and exit out once done.

If you don't have `csh` you could try other shells too:

- /bin/ksh
- /bin/zsh
- /bin/tcsh

#### Tell bash to ignore init files

You can also use the same trick above but instead call `bash` and tell it to ignore reading the `profile` file or `bashrc`.

```
$ ssh -t remoteserver '/bin/bash --noprofile'
```

*OR*

```
$ ssh -t remoteserver '/bin/bash --norc'
```

*excerpt from the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)*

```
--noprofile
          Do not read either the system-wide startup file /etc/profile or any 
          of the personal  initialization  files  ~/.bash_profile,
          ~/.bash_login,  or  ~/.profile.   By  default,  bash  reads  these 
          files when it is invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION
          below).

--norc    Do not read and execute the personal initialization file ~/.bashrc 
          if the shell  is  interactive.   This  option  is  on  by default
          if the shell is invoked as sh.
```

Comment: Where do I get to a command line like that? Sorry, I'm a total beginner.

Comment: yes I think that will work!!! how does ssh work? I can't get to anything other than the tty prompt

Comment: Do you have another linux system from which you can `ssh` into this one?

Comment: well it's a virtual machine, so could I do it from a different vm or my host system?

Comment: @SamFrench - yup, another VM should do.